# Paginating Query Results with Search Criteria

Tags: java, spring, pagination, thymeleaf

I am having trouble figuring out how to switch between pages of paginated search results while maintaining the search criteria used to find the results. I have a single page with a form with input fields for several search criteria and a button to retrieve the query results based on the provided criteria. Below the form is a table to display the results and a pagination bar to choose which page of data to display in the table. Requesting the data by page number and size with the criteria is working perfectly and the pagination bar also already works. They only issue is that the search criteria is passed to the controller from the form using a submit button and then when clicking on the pagination bar links to switch pages, the search criteria is being passed to the controller empty since the form is not resubmitted when hitting the same controller method from the pagination link. Basically, whenever I use a pagination link, I do switch pages, but all of the search criteria are lost so I end up paginating through all of the results without the search criteria applied. How can I keep the search criteria while switching pages with my pagination links?

Thymeleaf Pagination Bar:

```
<!-- Pagination Bar -->
        <div th:fragment='paginationbar' th:if="${results}">
            <div>
                <ul class='pagination pagination-centered'>
                    <li th:class="${page.firstPage}?'disabled':''">
                    <span th:if='${page.firstPage}'>← First</span>
                    <a th:if='${not page.firstPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size})}'>← First</a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:class="${page.hasPreviousPage}? '' : 'disabled'">
                    <span th:if='${not page.hasPreviousPage}'>«</span>
                    <a th:if='${page.hasPreviousPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.currentNumber-2},size=${page.size})}' title='Go to previous page'>«</a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:each='item : ${page.items}' th:class="${item.current}? 'active' : ''">
                    <span th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>1</span>
                    <a th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${item.number-1},size=${page.size})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:class="${page.hasNextPage}? '' : 'disabled'">
                    <span th:if='${not page.hasNextPage}'>»</span>
                    <a th:if='${page.hasNextPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.currentNumber},size=${page.size})}' title='Go to next page'>»</a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:class="${page.lastPage}? 'disabled' : ''">
                    <span th:if='${page.lastPage}'>Last →</span>
                    <a th:if='${not page.lastPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.totalPages - 1},size=${page.size})}'>Last →</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model, @ModelAttribute("criteria") UserSearchCriteria criteria, 
        @RequestParam(name="page", required=false, defaultValue="0") Integer pageNumber, @RequestParam(name="size", required=false, defaultValue="10") Integer pageSize) {

    Page<User> results = userService.findUsers(criteria, new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize));
    PageWrapper<User> page = new PageWrapper<User>(results, "/users/search");
    model.addAttribute("results", results);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    return "users";
}
```

Screenshot of Search Page with Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/njJ3P.png

Comment: hi can you please attach few screen shots for reference.

Comment: I just added a screenshot behind the link at the bottom of the initial post.

Comment: From pagination results you can pass the search results using url using ? and & for multiple values like ${page.url?searchRes=" +value you need to pass } and then from controller you receive using request params

Comment: or else you can using ajax so that you can use  post which will not expose url

Comment: I ended up figuring it out using a similar approach as recommended by Pradeep. I am utilizing a PageWrapper class to handle the logic of building the links in the pagination bar and I was able to pass to this wrapper the current url which contained all of the search parameters. Previously I was using only the base url for the search path without the parameters.

Comment: Glad that you figured out the issue .Shall I post this suggestion as answer so that you can accept and close this?

Answer (score -1):

Initially I was just passing the base url for the search path to the PageWrapper in my controller method (without any of the search parameters). This path I am passing is being used to construct the links included in the pagination bar. I found out that instead I could pass the full current url that was used to reach the enclosing controller method which includes the search parameters. Passing this to the PageWrapper instead allowed the pagination links to include the search parameters. (My issue was that I didn't know I could retrieve the full current url with search parameters. The @CurrentUrl annotation is custom and resolves the current url from the HttpServletRequest.)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model, @ModelAttribute("criteria") UserSearchCriteria criteria, @CurrentUrl String currentUrl, Paging paging) {

    Page<User> results = userService.findUsers(criteria, new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize));
    PageWrapper<User> page = new PageWrapper<User>(results, currentUrl);
    model.addAttribute("results", results);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    return "users";
}
```